# Android Studio : auto build like Eclipse

Tags: android, android-studio

I decided to use Android Studio after using Eclipse since years. But I found one bad thing about Android Studio for me. Indeed, it seems it's not possible to have the auto build feature like in Eclipse. When files are modified and saved, I can't see if my project has errors, warnings, etc..

So is there any way to enable this ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

IntelliJ (Android Studio) has a whole different build system to eclipse. It has incremental compiling that is different.

IntelliJ will tell you if something has an error / warning the the CURRENT open file.

So short answer no you can't. You will see the errors as you open the files, you can select "rebuild project" from the menu which will show you these errors. You can also enable "auto-import" for Gradle that may help.

You don't want to be doing 'rebuild project' all the time. So I'd recommend getting used to it.

Also you shouldn't rely on compile errors for coding, you should safely refactor and it should be a surprise when something pop's up a compile warning and you have to fix it.

---

You should read the IntelliJ FAQ

> Q: What happened to incremental compilation? How do I compile my
> project?
>
> A: It's there, but works slightly other way. By default
> IntelliJ IDEA compiles files only when it's needed (when you run your
> app or explicily invoke the Make action), and so saves system
> resources for other tasks that can be more important at the moment.
> The compilation is incremental: IntelliJ IDEA keeps track of
> dependencies between source files and recompiles only if a file has
> been changed.
>
> Files with compilation errors are highlighted, and so are the folders
> containing them — so you can easily analyze them via Project view. To
> see a list of all files with compilation errors, select Scope |
> Problems from the View As combobox of the Project view. After each
> compilation, IntelliJ IDEA constantly performs background code
> analysis on files with errors, and removes the red highlighting
> automatically when you've fixed them.
>
> To enable compiling files on every save, you can use the EclipseMode
> plugin: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=3822 (third-party
> development, not bundled).
>
> To be able to run code with errors, you can select the Eclipse
> compiler in Settings dialog, Compiler, Java Compiler and add the
> -proceedOnError option to the Additional command line parameters for the compiler.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html

Comment: "You don't want to be doing 'rebuild project' all the time": YES, I do! "Also you shouldn't rely on compile errors for coding": WRONG, this is a great approach to ensuring you've fixed all areas -- break things such that the compiler will complain.

Comment: Sorry Blundell, I was a little emphatic. My point is to use the compiler like any other tool, to help you write good code. For instance, one approach is to add a parameter to a method, then go fix all the places that don't compile. This ensures that you thoughtfully consider each and every caller to determine the correct value for the new parameter. If you have a fast build system that rebuilds quickly, you can use that to your advantage. Yes, you can use refactoring tools, but they'll just set a default value you may not want.

Comment: I know what you mean. But I prefer refactoring tools over build tools. cmd f6, add parameter, dialog box - select the default you want, and it will also run you through each place before you confirm it :-)

Comment: Then you might want to read this book "Refactoring Improving the Design of Existing Code" http://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html to understand why the 'break it then fix it' approach is dangerous

Comment: @miguel wouldn't say coding style which is independent. It's more workflow and it should be expected that a different tool has a different workflow - else why use a different tool? It's also difficult to acclimatise to a new workflow, but only then can you compare which is better for you.

Comment: @Blundell, there are many situations when autobuild helps a lot. And it not only "break it then fix it" (which I personally find a legit approach). Let's say you have updated a 3rd party lib and there were non-backwards compatible changes. And, honestly, I do not get this "saves system resources for other tasks that can be more important at the moment". This is nonsense. Eclipse handles huge workspaces (200+ projects) with source code dependencies just fine. A single Android application with jar dependencies can be built in a heartbeat.

Comment: "Tell us what you need, we'll teach you how to get rid of it".... Android Studio totally SUCKS on so much domains, and nobody in Google wants to admit it ! And we're forced to use it. DAMN, if it's not dictatorship, I don't find any other word for it !!!! :((((

Comment: `IntelliJ will tell you if something has an error / warning the the CURRENT open file.` This really sucks. When you have 1000 errors showing up at once, you know the problem is not your code but the project setup.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, but I dare to say that this editor, especially Android Studio, is the biggest sh!t I've ever seen. When I comment out methods or constructors I don't see something in the CURRENT window, because it's commented out then, so I need to know where this error occurs in OTHER windows. Otherwise I could work with vim or gedit.

Comment: What a lame answer, the facts are correct, but instead of highlighing intellijs shortcomings author is suggesting tips to write better code.

Comment: @Orabîg "Tell us what you need, we'll teach you how to get rid of it" so true!

Comment: @Blundell taking something that has found a widespread use IMHO was a bad move in A.S. I personally, having the feature highlighting multiple issues as I work saves me so much time and brain-memory power. Unfortunately A.S. / gradle doesn't even give you the entire list of errors, it rather gives you chunks every time. This is UTTERLY annoying... I do appreciate the link to the Eclipse-style plugin, but getting used to something inferior is beyond my willingness...

Comment: The most interesting thing is that if you undo the edit action which lead to compile error the files in the "Project" area won't be underlined with red anymore. So it seems to work in one direction.

Answer (score 20):

To enable auto build you can follow next steps: click on Android Studio/Preferences/Compiler and turn on the *Make project automatically* option. 
[image]
This will work for all projects imported in Android Studio.

If you want the option only on some projects: go to Run/Edit configurations and add the Make option in its *Before launch* task list.[image]

Comment: "Make project automatically" never worked for me. I don't see any improvements. I am not debugging or running an app at the moment. In fact I have disconnected my android device.

Answer (score 3):

Android studio, does not have auto build feature which is present in eclipse.

One thing we can do , if we change public fields, class name, methods, variables referred in another class eclipse will show that 
  changed field is referred by another class by auto building the project. So we need to re-build the project in android studio.

It will show errors if the changed fields are referred by any other class.
  It is the way to check whether fields or method, class names referred by any other class.