# Android Studio not rebuilding when clicking run

Tags: android, android-studio

For one of my projects, Android Studio sometimes doesn't rebuild when I click run. I have to manually click rebuild project, wait for it to rebuild, and then click run to deploy the app to the device. If I don't manually click rebuild project first, the previous version of the app will be deployed to the device.

This takes a lot of time and is very annoying while developing the app..

Is there a setting that I could possibly have changed accidentally?

It only happens for one certain project. I tried looking into the settings but I could not find anything that may cause this.

EDIT: it only happens when the only change since the last build is in XML files.

Comment: I had this issue once. Have you tried disabling Instant run? It helped in my case.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/2826147

Comment: @Gotiasits I disabled it, but that did not help.

Comment: Do you have nested resource folders? Check this solution instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317822/rebuild-required-after-changing-xml-layout-files-in-android-studio It's similar to your problem

Answer (score -2):

Try to Restart Android Studio by clearing all caches

> Click on File > Invalidate caches/Restart

[image]

Hope it Helps.