# Android Studio - compiler error with no changes in project window

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, lint

Recently I've started to have following problem with my Android Studio installation. I've already tried to wipe everything out and "start fresh" as I've spent whole day trying to find a solution, of course without luck ("wipe out" - uninstalling, removing sdk, .gradle, .Android3.5 folders etc).

The problem can be described as follows. I have two classes, A and B. Within an A I have a public static v field, which is accessed from method in class B. Everything compiles without a problem. 
Now, normally when I remove A.v from code I should've got an instant visual error within project window (java's B file should be red-underlined) but there is no to be seen and that's the problem.

Moreover, when I click on the B file, somehow it refreshes properly, marking faulty line of code and marking B file in the project window. 
Also, when v field is added back to A class, the marking on the B file in project window gets removed instantly (correct behaviour).

Please help

Additional info: I'm using Window 8 machine and recently I've been installing some Windows updates (could this somehow introduce this faulty behaviour?)

Comment: IntelliJ (and AndroidStudio is built on IntelliJ) doesn't compile everything instantly. What happens if you select to use the Eclipse Compiler under `Build, Execution, Deployment > Java Compiler`?

Comment: But I don't see a big problem with that. If you run it, you'll see the errors in any way.

Comment: I cannot find Java Compiler under Build, Execution, Deployment. I forgot to add that this is an Android-mobile project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio : auto build like Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480822/android-studio-auto-build-like-eclipse)

Comment: The problem is that I've already had my workflow and that functionality is really important to me, to see the faulty changes in files

Comment: You could try do build it with gradle if it is suited in your workflow. (I think the command is `./gradlew compileJava`)

Comment: What about the [EclipseMode Plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=3822)? It seems old but it may work

Comment: I'm using gradle. This happens on a fresh project too, creating simple Android-gradle project with the use of a wizard.

Comment: The thing is it's just stopped working, at the whim. Without any significant change in the project or ide

Comment: I think it is weird that it worked before.

Comment: Tell me about it, have been trying to find what's going on whole day..

Comment: I think the answer of the question I've linked before explains this. IntelliJ/Android Studio compiles classes **when it is needed**. If you change a class, the other classes are not recompiled.

Comment: Is there a `Compiler Entry` in `Build, Execution, Deployment`?

Comment: Yes there is Compiler Entry

Comment: Is there a `Java Compiler` entry inside the `Compiler` entry? Can you select `Eclipse` instead of `javac` there?

Comment: No, there isn't